# Saving a meeting in my outlook calender from a cakephp website

Tags: php, laravel, cakephp, microsoft-graph-api, outlook-calendar

I am working on a website that was build using cakephp. I want to add the option for visitors of the website to make a appointment, then this should automatically be added to my outlook calender.

I found [this tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/tutorials/php?context=outlook%2Fcontext)  from Microsoft on how to use the Microsoft graph API with php, however its made in laravel since I am not familiar with cakephp I was wondering on if it is a lot diffrent to do the same in cakephp or maybe there is a better or simpler solution. I wasnt realy able to find a guide or example made with cakephp (if you know of one that would be great).

Any help is appreciated, thanks!

Comment: I believe that API is about adding to someone's calendar when you fully control their Outlook system, e.g. if you're a company doing scheduling of internal meetings. There's no way I know of to "automatically" add anything to some random visitor's calendar; being able to do so would surely be attacked immediately by spammers. What you can do is provide an iCal formatted file for them to download. Many calendar systems (Outlook, Google, and more) will recognize the file format and allow them to import it.

Comment: the system is so not to add to a visitor's calender but to the calendar of emplyees